# Video HTML tag not showing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, html5-video, rails-activestorage, actiontext

When I preview a blob in _blob.html.erb, I can preview images, but I'm having difficulty embedding video. The `<video>` tag below is not showing in the webpage.

If I run the `blob.service_url` function and paste its output where it is in the line `<source src="<%= blob.service_url %>" type="video/mp4">`, and then manually paste the video tag into the Chrome HTML, a video player appears as I want it to, but I can't figure out why the video tag won't compile directly from the erb.html file. Does anyone know why the tag is not rendering?

```
  <% if blob.representable? %>
    <% if blob.video? %>
      <video width="1024" height="768" controls>
        <source src="<%= blob.service_url %>" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <%= blob.service_url %>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem with the help of this post: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36725.

It turned out that I needed to modify my configuration because various tags were by default disallowed. In application.rb, I needed to add:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'style'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'controls'

  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'video'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'source'
end
```

Comment: That's the right answer for `rails 6.0.1`, however in `rails 6.0.3` this does not help

Comment: Works for me on Rails 6.0.3.4. 